# Use Multi-Player Save in Single-Player and vice versa

Tags: civilization-5

I am looking for a way to use my Civilization V multiplayer save in single player. Background is that I play a lot of games with friends but they quit once it is clear who is winning. However, I would like to play it to an end. Some for achievements, some for fun. It seems that you cannot do this.

On the other side, I would love to play some round where I have a hard time with a bot with a friend or two.
Is this possible? Can you just edit a value in the save game that states what type it is? If so which value?

I cannot even see the save game from multiplayer if I start single player. If I copy it manually in the right folder it appears but the start button is disabled.

I can play the game if i start multiplayer and make my friend a ki. But I have the feeling that multiplayer and single player ki are not the same.

UPDATE: I own G&K and also BNW. Looking for a solution for the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to using a multi-player save in single-player is to kick the Humans. When you load the multi-player save, you will be in the multiplayer 'Staging Room'. By selecting the red X next to a player you will 'kick' them, so that they are set to AI. Although it will still be launched as a multiplayer game, you will be able to play without the other human players. See images below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately i want to play it as single player with mods like IGE.

Comment: @FrTerstappen Okay, that makes sense. I can't help with that, but maybe someone else will have a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

[Wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Civilization_5_Multiplayer_Tips)

Check the Saving/Loading section at the bottom

Comment: Don't just link somewhere and tell readers to find the answer there.  Please summarize the information at the link relevant to this question.  That way, if ever the link goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it saves people a click.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked article: "NOTE! This is outdated Multiplayer article, This relates to version 1.0.0.20 (before G&K and BNW)" but i have G&K and BNW. Someone deleted the tags for this two expansions from my question.